# create form in templates(html) or in forms.py? :django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm new in django and python. I want to have a form in one of my website's page. When user fills the data, i want to create an xml file with user input. so i need to access the user's data (form data) from views.py. I want to know am i allowed to only have form in html? if yes, how can i use it's data in views.py? i mean should i have always a class defined in forms.py that contains my form fields? If the second way is a rule, what should i do with templates(html)? (It means if i define my fields in a class in forms.py, should i redefine them in templates(html) too? and how can i use data in views.py)

i need some kinds of input in my form: checkbox, input type:text and input type:file

I really need your answers. Thank you :)

Comment: submitted form data will be in request.POST dictionary.

Comment: How can i use it? and before that, i want to know where should i create my form?(in templates or in forms.py)?

Comment: [Working with forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/)

Comment: I don't wanna work with data base(models.py). Should i use forms.py or that's enough to create my form in (templates)html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can totally define your form in raw html and write a view which just processes the post data. But then we come to point where you would invent the wheel once again. Django provides a bunch of field classes which provide html rendering and data validation (never trust user input).

I suggest you read the [online documentation for forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs).